# notification bar in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

hey I am creating a web application for an e learning project. 
For that I am doing a notification bar which must give the looks and feel of Facebook's notification bar. We are using angular material design for designing the site. does anyone have a working examples or code for this?

[image: This is what i am looking for]

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this one: https://github.com/cgross/angular-notify